# auto-escape hint is not working in liferay models

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6

To prevent XSS attacks in liferay I followed the auto-escape hint concept for domain model attributes. 
I added the below configuration in portlet-model-hints.xml

```
<field name="lastName" type="String" localized="true">
    <hint name="auto-escape">false</hint>
</field>
```

And from the data entry screens I added the data

```
<b><span>UNTRUSTED DATA</span></b> <script>alert("hai middlename")</script>
```

for lastname field. But from the view pages of public which doesn't use the  tags are displaying the disigned output and with the alerts. And designed output is not displayed when we use  related tags.

So my doubt here is, what is the exact use of "auto-escape" here?
and will this auto-escape works only with  tags?

Can someone please make my understanding clear about the auto-escape hint.

Answer (score 0):

the auto-escape attribute by default is true and make an escape of html using the liferay class HtmlUtil.escape replacing the html tag with the html entity. There is comment in the source of HtmlUtil

```
    // Escape using XSS recommendations from
    // http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross_Site_Scripting
    // #How_to_Protect_Yourself
```

Comment: Hi Romeo Sheshi, Thanks for the reply. I did the same thing. I mean applied the HtmlUtil.escape() in all my html codebase. But I'm checking for a generic approach to handle it.

Comment: I don't know if i get correctly the problem, auto-escape by default is true  and when true call the method  HtmlUtil.escape()  so it would be a generic approach.  If this is not working o you want to apply globally you can create a hook an XSSPortletFilter  so it apply to your request parameters

Comment: Yeah, This Filter can be applied if we want a generic way to filter the request parameters before save. But need a generic way to filter(escape) the outgoing parameters before display.  For this, like you said, I've used HtmlUtil.escape() method itself. But this is not a generic way, we have to call this method in each and every place where we want to display the values.

Comment: I see in your question that you use auto escape false, in this way the content of field is not escaped and this doesn't prevent the xss attack is this correct? Can you make me an example of complete case of use it think I don't understand well what you want to reach